# RPE for a timed set?

Tags: strength-training

I've learnt the RPE scale based on reps-in-reserve  (e.g. 8 = 2 reps left, 9 = 1 rep left, 10 = max).

If someone were to ask you for an RPE for a timed exercise, such as holding a plank for 1-minute, how would you determine your exertion level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three options come to my mind:

**The simplest - and probably least helpful - variant** would be to just use a [normalized Borg scale](https://www.topendsports.com/testing/rpe-intensity.htm), which is basically the origin of the RPE tables for strength training. However, terms like 'moderate' 'hard', 'very very hard' are pretty vague and the 1:1 mapping onto strength excercises seem a bit off. At least I wouldn't describe any RPE 7 sets that I do as 'very hard'

I heard from a lot of people that use bar **velocity as a gauge for RPE** instead of the 'RPE 8 == two reps left in the tank', as described [here](https://www.powerliftingtowin.com/how-to-rate-rpes-correctly/), for example. The blog post talks about gauging RPE for the big lifts. But personally, I found the velocity cue very useful for high-rep bodyweight excercises like timed pushups or burpees. It obviously doesn't work for planks (although I could imagine you could utilize the amount of muscle tremor as a cue for establishing RPE).

Finally, something untested, but it might be worth a try. **Use your normal RPE table, but  read the percentages as '% of time until muscle failure'** instead of reading them as '% of 1RM':

- Take a strength-specific RPE-Table like this one and just look at the first column: 
  [image]

  *taken from http://dimeperformance.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Table-2.jpg*
- Do a set of planks until failure (let's hope you're not [that guy](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/02/23/us/new-planking-world-record-trnd/index.html)), take note of the time. This is your 100%, or RPE10 time
- A few days after, do a set of planks for 91% of the time you did before, take note how it feels, how much your muscles tremble etc... Now you know what RPE 8 feels like.
- continue doing this for other RPEs.

Comment: ***Eight hours and fifteen minutes?!***